# how to make BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener returns result at app first luanch

Tags: android

I have a class which I implement `BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener` class in it. 
the problem that I have is. the `checkConnected()` method will not show anything except the app restart once: how can i get it work at the application very first launch(after installation)?

```
public class CheckConnection {
String name;
String address;
Context context;
public CheckConnection(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
   checkConnected();
}

public void checkConnected()
{
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(this.context, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
}

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener serviceListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
    {

        for (BluetoothDevice device : proxy.getConnectedDevices())
        {
            name = device.getName();
            address = device.getAddress();
            Log.i("onServiceConnected", "|" + device.getName() + " | " + device.getAddress() + " | " + proxy.getConnectionState(device) + "(connected = "
                    + BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED + ")");
        }
        Repository repository = new Repository(context);
        repository.open();
        List<BtDevice> btDevices = repository.SelectAllDevices();
        for (BtDevice btDevice:btDevices){
            if (btDevice.getDeviceId().equals(address)){
                btDevice.setConnectionStatus("CONNECTED");
                repository.EditItem(btDevice);
                repository.close();
            }
        }
        BtAdapter btAdapter = BtAdapter.createAdapter();
        btAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by doing following things: 
- turn this class into a service.

```
public class CheckConnection extends Service {
String name = null;
String address = null;
ResultReceiver nameReceiver = null;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    nameReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");

    checkConnected();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void checkConnected()
{
     BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(this, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
     BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(this,serviceListener,BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
}

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener serviceListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
    {
        Log.i("onserviceConnected","onserviceConnected");

        for (BluetoothDevice device : proxy.getConnectedDevices())
        {
            name = device.getName();
            address = device.getAddress();
            Log.i("onCheckConnected()", "|" + device.getName() + " | " + device.getAddress() + " | " + proxy.getConnectionState(device) + "(connected = "
                    + BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED + ")");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id",address);
            nameReceiver.send(10,bundle);
        }

        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy);
    }
};
```

}

and use  `ResultReceiver` to send data from this class to the activity then use  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to update the adapter . at this point the problem is still exits. it was working like before and  to see the changes on the adapter it still needs the app to restart in someway.

```
   public class NameReceiver extends ResultReceiver{

    public NameReceiver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (resultCode==10){
                    Bundle bundle = resultData;
                    deviceId =bundle.getString("id");
                    BtAdapter btAdapter = BtAdapter.createAdapter();
                    repository = new Repository(MainActivity.this);
                    devices = getDevicesFromDb();
                    for (BtDevice thisDevice: devices)
                    {
                        if (thisDevice.getDeviceId().equals(deviceId)){
                            thisDevice.setConnectionStatus("CONNECTED");
                            repository.EditItem(thisDevice);
                            repository.close();
                            btAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

what I did here was on the Class that implements  `ResultReceiver`  after getting the data from `CheckConnection` class and making changes on DB instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` I called a method responsible for creating the adapter in MainActivity to **recreate** the adapter. the question that I have is a good practice to do such a thing?

```
public void createAdapter() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = BtAdapter.createAdapter();
    adapter.BtAdapter1(getDevicesFromDb());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    repository.close();


}
public class NameReceiver extends ResultReceiver{

    public NameReceiver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (resultCode==10){
                    Bundle bundle = resultData;
                    deviceId =bundle.getString("id");
                    BtAdapter btAdapter = BtAdapter.createAdapter();
                    repository = new Repository(MainActivity.this);
                    devices = getDevicesFromDb();
                    for (BtDevice thisDevice: devices)
                    {
                        if (thisDevice.getDeviceId().equals(deviceId)){
                            thisDevice.setConnectionStatus("CONNECTED");
                            repository.EditItem(thisDevice);
                        }
                    }
                    repository.close();
                    createAdapter();
                    Log.i("oid",deviceId);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}